# Count Specific Item Names in Cell

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to count the instances of which the items have been added to each cell.

Please refer the screenshot.

I need to Count how many:

- SIGMA CANON LENS
- SIGMA NIKON LENS
- SIGMA SONY LENS

are there in the column. Please help me on ow to get this done

[image: My Google Sheet]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A2:A), CHAR(10))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"))
```